# PHP, JQuery and Wordpress: repeating URL

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress theme with JQuery. Everything seems normal but, when I click in any section, the site repeat the URL:

```
mydomain.com/#mydomain.com/section.php
```

This is a problem. How can I solve it?

Thank you so much,
King regards.

Comment: I think in link has `<a href='#' ` and it one page template. Please ellaborate your problem

Comment: This is the code I am using: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>`